# heroku runaway database process causing timeout with Laravel app

Tags: laravel, heroku, heroku-postgres

A few days ago, I ran a database query with some bad code and it caused a recursion where database entries were created into infinity. I stopped it as quickly as I could and deleted the redundant entries from the database immediately.

Today, I started getting timeout errors when I query the (Production) database and there are no problems with the same code on the test database.

How do I find and stop this process in heroku? It is a Laravel app if that matters.

Comment: "Today, I started getting timeout errors when I query the (Production) database and there are no problems with the same code on the test database."—what makes you think this has anything to do with your first paragraph? We can't help without knowing much more. Please be more specific about the errors and the database issue you believe to be related.

Comment: I say that because nothing has changed. If I knew what info to give you, I would give it.